# Handle image after download

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Im using CopyToAsync to download an image to a local server. After download I have to Upload the file to another webserver using FluentFTP.

My code to download the image is :

```
public static async Task DownloadImage(Entity.LoginResult loginResult, string saveFolder, string image, string saveFile)
    {
        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(saveFile);
        string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(saveFile);
        {
            saveFile = GetValidUrlString(filename, "-", 255) + extension;
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), apiUrl + image + "/download"))
                {
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "CBX-SIMPLE-TOKEN Token=" + loginResult.token);
                    var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
                    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        using (var fs = new FileStream(saveFolder + saveFile, FileMode.Create))
                        {                                
                            await response.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

After calling DownloadImage i would like to check if the file is downloaded like:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(saveFolder + media.filename))
{ Call ftp  }
```

I get the following to errors when ftp'ing the images

1. The image isnt downloaded (System.IO.File.Exist = False)
2. The image is in progress and FTP fails because the file is in use.

Can anyone tell me how to use async/await so both Download and upload is done

Comment: what's the value of response.StatusCode ?

Comment: Ill only progress if its System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK (if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK))

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54883668/await-httpcontent-copytoasync-results-in-empty-target-stream

Comment: It appears you're not awaiting this Task. Why don't you make `DownloadImage` at least return a `bool` value, to signal that it succeeded or failed (hence, change the return type to `Task<bool>`). -- Where are you calling this method from? Can you post that code? -- What type of application is this?

Comment: following on from @Jimi's comment you should be doing `var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);`

Answer (score 0):

1. Change line `var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;`
   to `var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);`
   In company i am currently working, `.Result` in tasks like that was not working
   properly sometimes.
2. If downloading fails, throw.

   if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
   {
   throw new Exception("download failed").
   }
3. To ensure that downloading took place, you need to call it with await like this
   `await DownloadImage(params)`
4. Good practice is "once async, all async". Meaning when you use one async, all your code should be async.